# SQL using a function in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, function, triggers

I am creating a a trigger in SQL that will insert into another table after Insert on it. However I need to fetch a Value from the table to increment to be used in the insert.

I have a AirVisionSiteLog table. On insert on the table I would like for it to insert into another SiteLog table. However in order to do this I need to fetch the last Entry Number of the Site from the SiteLog table. Then on its insert take that result and increase by one for the new Entry Number. I am new to Triggers and Functions so I am not sure how to use them correctly. I believe I have a function to retrieve and increment the Entry Number however I am not sure how to use it in the Trigger.

My Function -

```
CREATE FUNCTION AQB_RMS.F_GetLogEntryNumber

(@LocationID int)

RETURNS INTEGER

AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @MaxEntry Integer,
        @EntryNumber Integer

 Set @MaxEntry = (Select Max(SL.EntryNumber) FROM AQB_MON.AQB_RMS.SiteLog SL
                WHERE SL.LocationID = @LocationID)

 SET @EntryNumber = @MaxEntry + 1

 RETURN @EntryNumber

 END
```

My Trigger and attempt to use the Function -

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [AQB_RMS].[SiteLogCreate] on [AQB_MON].[AQB_RMS].[AirVisionSiteLog]
 AFTER INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN

declare @entrynumber int
declare @corrected int

set @corrected = 0

INSERT INTO [AQB_MON].[AQB_RMS].[SiteLog]
        ([SiteLogTypeID],[LocationID],[EntryNumber],[SiteLogEntry]
       ,[EntryDate],[Corrected],[DATE_CREATED],[CREATED_BY])

SELECT st.SiteLogTypeID, l.LocationID, 
 (select AQB_RMS.F_GetLogEntryNumber from [AQB_MON].[AQB_RMS].[SiteLog] sl 
 where sl.LocationID = l.LocationID)
 , i.SiteLogEntry, i.EntryDate, @corrected, i.DATE_CREATED, i.CREATED_BY

from inserted i
left join AQB_MON.[AQB_RMS].[SiteLogType] st on st.SiteLogType = i.SiteLogType
left join AQB_MON.AQB_RMS.Location l on l.SourceSiteID = i.SourceSiteID

 END 

 GO
```

Comment: There are so many thing I would suggest changing here. Honestly in my opinion your whole approach is wrong here. You want to avoid scalar functions whenever possible and instead use an inline table valued function. In this case you could do that. However, your function is DIY version of an identity. This is fraught with issues because of things like concurrency. Roll your own identities never work well all the time. Instead either use an identity or a sequence. Then you don't need the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are close.

At this part of the query in the trigger: (I set the columns vertically so that the difference is more noticable)

```
SELECT st.SiteLogTypeID, 
       l.LocationID,
       (select AQB_RMS.F_GetLogEntryNumber from [AQB_MON].[AQB_RMS].[SiteLog] sl where sl.LocationID = l.LocationID),
       i.SiteLogEntry,
       i.EntryDate,
       @corrected,
       i.DATE_CREATED,
       i.CREATED_BY
```

...should be:

```
SELECT st.SiteLogTypeID,
       l.LocationID, 
       AQB_RMS.F_GetLogEntryNumber(select l.LocationID from [AQB_MON].[AQB_RMS].[SiteLog] sl where sl.LocationID = l.LocationID),
       i.SiteLogEntry,
       i.EntryDate,
       @corrected,
       i.DATE_CREATED,
       i.CREATED_BY
```

So basically, you would call the function name with the query as the parameter, which the results thereof should only be one row with a value.

Note that in my modified example, I added the `l.LocationID` after the select in the function call, so I'm not sure if this is what you need, but change that to match your needs. Because I'm not sure of the exact column that you need, add a comment should there be other issues.

Comment: Note the caveats that Sean mentioned above. Also, I was assuming MySQL as both tags were present at the time.

Comment: I just assumed sql server as the syntax is right for sql server. :)

Comment: I receive `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.` and `Incorrect syntax near ')'`

Comment: Ok, then now knowing sql server syntax, which I'm unfortunately not as familiar, try this at the line with the query:  `select AQB_RMS.F_GetLogEntryNumber(select l.LocationID from [AQB_MON].[AQB_RMS].[SiteLog] sl where sl.LocationID = l.LocationID)` ... the only change is the select before the function name as it was orginally.